# Frame just on the bottom of a graphics object in a grid

Tags: graphics, frame

Given a set of Graphics in a grid with frames on all borders of the first and third object:

```
  GraphicsGrid[{Table[Graphics[Circle[]], {4}]}, 
 Frame -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> True, {1, 3} -> True}}]
```

How can I put a frame **just on the bottom** of those objects? This is probably a trivial problem, but I was not able to figure it out, unfortunately.

EDIT: Generating a frame separately for every single graphic is not feasible in my case, since I'm generating several GraphicsGrids with over a 100 objects automatically based on some data. And depending on whether some criterium is met I want to underline the graphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Apply the frame to the individual graphic object.

In order to do this programmatically assume that you have a list of graphic objects and a separate list of Booleans that indicate whether a frame is to be drawn or skipped. The criteria used in the decision can be anything in general as long as you produce a list of Booleans.

I will create a minimal example that duplicates your question.

```
graphicsList = Table[Graphics[Circle[]], {4}];
criteriaList = {False, True, False, True}
```

The strategy is to replace the graphics in `graphicsList` where the same position in `criteriaList` is `True` with a frame applied to the bottom of that graphic.

1. Get the positions

   ```
   positions = Position[criteriaList, True] // Flatten
   ```
2. Replace the graphics

   ```
   graphicsList[[positions]] = 
    graphicsList[[positions]] /. 
     Graphics[g__] -> 
      Graphics[g, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, 
       FrameTicks -> None]
   ```
3. Plot the results in the grid

   ```
   GraphicsGrid[{graphicsList}]
   ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! Applying it separately to every single graphic is not feasible in my case, since I'm generating several GraphicsGrids with over a 100 objects automatically based on some data. And depending on whether some criterium is met I want to underline the graphic. I edited the question about so this becomes more clear :).

Comment: @holistic Updated to handle  the general problem programmatically.

Comment: Great, thanks again :) !

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like:

```
GraphicsGrid[{Table[
   Item[Graphics[Circle[]], Frame -> If[OddQ[i], {{False, False}, {True, False}}, False]], 
   {i, 6}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]